# Sequential aggregation with a single call of pivot_wider

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

Consider the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c("a", "a", "b", "a"))
```

By applying the code below

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(x, names_from = y, values_from = y, values_fn = length, names_prefix = "tot_", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  mutate(per_a = 100*tot_a / rowSums(select(.,starts_with("tot_")))) %>% 
  mutate(per_b = 100*tot_b / rowSums(select(.,starts_with("tot_"))))
```

one gets the result

```
   <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     2     1  66.7  33.3
 2     2     1     0 100     0
```

My question is: Is it possible to get the same result using a ***single*** call of `pivot_wider`, that is, without any `mutate`?

Comment: what about `proportions(table(df), 1)*100`?

Comment: Thanks, @Onyambu. However, the motivation of my question is to find out whether such a result can be accomplished by using a single `pivot_wider`.

Comment: I do not think so. The `value_fn` is an aggregating function, and so does not qualify in this case. Probably with one mutate call

Comment: The documentation says that `value_fn` can be a list of functions, @Onyambu.

Comment: yes, all aggregating. ie in that they work per group and give a unified/single result. in your case, you have group a, and b which are dependent since 66.7 is obtained by counting all vlues in a AND B before dividing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to `group_by` twice I think if you want to do the `pivot_wider` once without `mutate`-ing each and every `per`centage column separately.

```
df %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  count(name="tot") %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(per = tot / sum(tot)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = x, names_from=y, values_from=c(tot,per))

## A tibble: 2 x 5
## Groups:   x [2]
#      x tot_a tot_b per_a  per_b
#  <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1     2     1 0.667  0.333
#2     2     1    NA 1     NA
```

That would be 'tidy' to me, in that you are doing all the calculations in 2 grouped sweeps in the long-form, tidy data, rather than trying to manually select multiple columns in wide format.

Answer (score 2):

additional solution option

**data.table**

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c("a", "a", "b", "a"))

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(df)[, list(tot = .N), by = list(x, y)] %>% 
  .[, perc := proportions(tot), by = list(y)] %>% 
  dcast(x ~ y, value.var = c("tot", "perc"), fill = 0)
#>    x tot_a tot_b    perc_a perc_b
#> 1: 1     2     1 0.6666667      1
#> 2: 2     1     0 0.3333333      0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**tidyverse**

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,1,1), y = c("a", "a", "b", "a"))

df %>%
  pivot_wider(
    x,
    names_from = y,
    values_from = y,
    values_fn = length,
    names_prefix = "tot_",
    values_fill = 0
  ) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("tot_"), proportions, .names = "{.col}_prop"))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>       x tot_a tot_b tot_a_prop tot_b_prop
#>   <dbl> <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     1      0.667          1
#> 2     2     1     0      0.333          0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>